# Passing arguments from one controller to another in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, parameter-passing

I want to pass an argument from one controller to another in rails.
This is first controller:

```
def create
@grouptorepo = Grouptorepo.new(params[:grouptorepo])
if @grouptorepo.save
  fileUpdate
  redirect_to create_usermailinglist_path, :group_id => @grouptorepo.group_id, :notice => "Group to repo relation created!"
else 
     render "new"
   end
end
```

And this is the second one:

```
def create
@g = params[:group_id]
@users = Usertogroup.where("group_id = ?", @g).first

@usermailinglist.user_id = @users.user_id

  if @usermailinglist.save
    redirect_to repositories_path, :notice => "Relation Created!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

@g is always nil I have no idea why.

Comment: redirect_to should redirect to a get action. But :create is a post action. what is the use case here?

Comment: after assigning group to repository admin will have an option to see if users in that group want to get mail notifications about the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax problem with the `create_usermailinglist_path` helper:

```
redirect_to create_usermailinglist_path(:group_id => @grouptorepo.group_id)
```

Also, if you want the `flash[:notice]`

```
if @grouptorepo.save
  fileUpdate
  redirect_to(create_usermailinglist_path(:group_id => @grouptorepo.group_id), :notice => "Group to repo relation created!")
else 
  render "new"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it still does not work.

    undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass

   app/controllers/usermailinglists_controller.rb:10:in `create'

Line 10 is this: @usermailinglist.user_id = @users.user_id

Comment: `@users` seems to refer to **several** users, not only one. You probably meant `@user` ?

Comment: it doesn't matter because it is only name. After changing it to @user it still doesn't work

Comment: ok i made some errors in syntax. Your answer helped me a lot thanks!

Comment: @MrYoshiji I find you here again! Greetings.